# passing directory name as a parameter

Tags: r

My current directory is `c:/users/akshay/Documents`

But all my data is in the directory "specdata" whose path address is `c:/users/akshay/Documents/specdata`

when i type these commands separately in console it works successfully.

```
path <- "C:/Users/akshay/Documents"
directory <- "specdata"
setwd(paste(path, directory, sep="/", collapse=NULL))
```

But when i use it in function like this it wont change my working directory.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory){
directory <- character(1)
path <- character(1)
path <- "C:/Users/akshay/Documents"
setwd(paste(path, directory, sep="/", collapse=NULL))    
}
```

But when i pass

```
>pollutantmean("specdata")
```

It wont change my working directory why is it so?
what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try returning the paste.  Also, you don't need the `character()` functions.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory){
   path <- "C:/Users/akshay/Documents"
   return(paste(path, directory, sep="/", collapse=NULL))
   }

pollutantmean("specdata")
```

Output:

```
> pollutantmean("test")
[1] "C:/Users/akshay/Documents/test"
```

Change directory:

```
pollutantmean<-function(directory){ + path<-"C:/Users/akshay/Documents" + setwd(paste(path,directory,sep="/",collapse=NULL)) + }
```

Comment: I think character() function was causing the problem. Can you tell me why that was needed?

Comment: You don't need the `character()` function because the `paste()` function will return a character anyways.  That's what is great about paste; you can just string a bunch of stuff together and it gives you a character.

Comment: Great!  Glad it work!  Please upvote and accept the answer if it is working correct for you now.

Comment: finally to wrap things up this function will change ur working directory

Comment: pollutantmean<-function(directory){
+     path<-"C:/Users/akshay/Documents"
+     setwd(paste(path,directory,sep="/",collapse=NULL))
+    }